# Create independent instances of the same class with DI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, mvvm-light

Originally I had `ChildUserControl` inside `ParentUserControl` inside `MainWindow` with this view-models (here only constructors):

```
public MainViewModel(IParentViewModel pvm) {}

public ParentViewModel(IChildViewModel cvm) {}

public ChildViewModel(IMessenger m) {}
```

And straightforward DI initialization in `ViewModelLocator`:

```
var container = SimpleIoc.Default;
container.Register<IMessenger, Messenger>();
container.Register<IParentViewModel, ParentViewModel>();
container.Register<IChildViewModel, ChildViewModel>();
container.Register<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
...
public IMainViewModel MainViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMainViewModel>();
```

Then I needed to add second `ParentUserControl` instance near the first one, and let them work independently. `MainViewModel` constructor became to look like this:

```
public MainViewModel(IParentViewModel pvm1, IParentViewModel pvm2) {}
```

But DI initialization changed dramatically:

```
container.Register<IMessenger, Messenger>();

container.Register<IParentViewModel>(
    () => new ParentViewModel(new ChildViewModel(container.GetInstance<IMessenger>("key1"))),
    "key1");

container.Register<IParentViewModel>(
    () => new ParentViewModel(new ChildViewModel(container.GetInstance<IMessenger>("key2"))),
    "key2");

container.Register<IMainViewModel>(() => new MainViewModel(
    container.GetInstance<IParentViewModel>("key1"),
    container.GetInstance<IParentViewModel>("key2")));
```

As you can see, now I have to point to concrete `ParentViewModel` and `ChildViewModel` classes in several places, and I also have to manually use `GetInstance` everywhere. I think this is wrong.

I there any way to resolve this problem? I guess it can't be resolved by *SimpleIoc*, but can *Unity* or *Ninject* help?

**Update (clarification)**

I'm searching the way to say to IoC container this idea: hey container, just create new instances of `IMainViewModel` and `IParentViewModel` every time they required, but starting from `IParentViewModel` DI resolving (aka `ParentViewModel` constructor dependencies resolving), you should enter "contextual mode" - create random key and perform all deeper types resolving using this created key (aka using `GetInstance` with this key).

Comment: I don't know SimpleIoc but this seems like a rather standard requirement, did you check the docs? I know with e.g. with MEF you just mark a class with [PartCreationPolicy( CreationPolicy.NonShared )] and that's it.

Comment: Yes, I checked the docs and more importantly checked SO questions - docs doesn't give me answer at all, while in SO I saw an opinion that it can't be resolved with SimpleIoc. According to `CreationPolicy.NonShared` - it will break things if I will also inject `IMessenger` instance in `ParentViewModel` besides `ChildViewModel` (it will give me different `IMessenger` instances in single Parent-Child "branch", while I need single instance in each of two branches). And ideally I would not want to heap business-entities with DI attributes, like `PartCreationPolicy` or similar. @stijn

Comment: If you want shared/non-shared DI depending on context then I doubt there is another way than something what you showed. Or you could just have a piece of factory-like code which acquires a non-shared messenger and then constructs both child and parent with it. Or you could have a single Messenger instance but have a decorator which passes either key1" / "key2" as arguments and use the decorated class in parent/child. Or...

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of workarounds, but all they finally leads either to adding DI-logic into business entities, or to replacing DI with service locators. Well, I still hope there is any way to resolve this problem just in DI-initialization code without affecting business logic. Anyway, thanks for your comments :)  @stijn

Comment: In Ninject you could use Named binding to allow the DI engine to lift some of your GetInstance requests - details are available here https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: Yes, it will help to resolve `MainViewModel`, despite it will add DI-specific logic into business entity, which I'm trying to avoid. But how to resolve `ParentViewModel` in that case? It will still receive the same `ChildViewModel` instance until we could do something like `ParentViewModel([Named("First","Second")] IChildViewModel cvm)` and it would resolve it. I doubt it could do this.  @Depechie